# A problem in Changeable Themes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, themes

I tried to test myself in JavaScript so I decided to make changeable themes website in ***codepen*** with JavaScript this is my code:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXLQt.png)

but it didn't work. please help me with it.

Comment: Please don't post your codes as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While **@LoaiMasri** was on a good track to solve the issue, there is still great way of improvement. Espacially to make the code shorter and more efficient if you have more themes to add.

First change you should consider over **LoaiMasri**'s solution is to use a `switch`-statement over listing tons of `if/else`-statements.

However that will be to complicated for more then just a handfull of themes. The most efficient way is to add the themes through CSS. For that you do **LoaiMasri**'s approach of using the `value`-attribute on the option tag. However give it a more direct value like `theme-1`, `theme-2`...

Then you use the script below:

```js
document.getElementById('Themes').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.body.className = "";
  let theme = document.getElementById("Themes").value;
  document.body.classList.add(theme);
});
```

`document.body.className = "";` -> This will remove all classes from the `body`-tag and works as a reset.

`let theme = document.getElementById("Themes").value;` -> That gets the `value` from the `option`-tag.

`document.body.classList.add(theme);` -> This will add now a class to the `body`-tag that equals the `value` of the `option`-tag.

All you now have to is to add classes to your CSS that equal the `value` of the `option`-tag. This will now solve the issue with 5 lines of JS code no matter how many themes you want to add (which is already smaller then **LoaiMasri**'s solution).

```js
document.getElementById('Themes').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.body.className = "";
  let theme = document.getElementById("Themes").value;
  document.body.classList.add(theme);
});
```

```css
.theme-1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.theme-2 {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


.theme-3 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<select id="Themes">
  <option value="theme-1">White</option>
  <option value="theme-2">Black</option>
  <option value="theme-3">Dark</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById("Themes").addEventListener("change", function () {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;
    });
```

**this is a answer but I recommended to add values as a number**

like this code

```
<select id="Themes">
                <option value="1">White</option>
                <option value="2">Black</option>
                <option value="3">Dark</option>
            </select>
```

```
document.getElementById("Themes").addEventListener("change", function () {
        let theme = document.getElementById("Themes").value;
        if (theme == 1) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
            document.body.style.color = "black";
        } else if (theme == 2) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
            document.body.style.color = "white";
        } else if (theme == 3) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "darkgrey";
            document.body.style.color = "white";
        }
    });
```

Comment: While the value is one apporach you should not use `if/else`-statements but a `switch`-statement.